# How to get scrapy FormRequest work

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to get data from the copyright-gov website using scrapy. this is my spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class CopyrightSpider(BaseSpider):
        name = "copyright_records"
        start_url = ["http://cocatalog.loc.gov/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?DB=local&PAGE=First"]

        def parse(self, response):
                yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                                formname='querybox',
                                                formdata={'Search_Arg': 'walt disney',  'Search_Code': 'Command Keyword'},
                                                callback=self.parse1)

        def parse1(self, response):

            open_in_browser(response)
```

I don't get errors when running the crawler however I see 0 pages are being crawled:

```
 2015-03-30 15:01:08-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.5 started (bot: copyright_records)
2015-03-30 15:01:08-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-03-30 15:01:08-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'copyright_records.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['copyright_records.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'copyright_records'}
2015-03-30 15:01:08-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-03-30 15:01:08-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-03-30 15:01:08-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-03-30 15:01:08-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-03-30 15:01:08-0700 [copyright_records] INFO: Spider opened
2015-03-30 15:01:08-0700 [copyright_records] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-03-30 15:01:08-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-03-30 15:01:08-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2015-03-30 15:01:08-0700 [copyright_records] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-03-30 15:01:08-0700 [copyright_records] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 30, 22, 1, 8, 867056),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
     'log_count/INFO': 7,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 30, 22, 1, 8, 865055)}
2015-03-30 15:01:08-0700 [copyright_records] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Not sure why its not working, any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a typo.

Replace:

```
start_url = ["http://cocatalog.loc.gov/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?DB=local&PAGE=First"]
```

with:

```
start_urls = ["http://cocatalog.loc.gov/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?DB=local&PAGE=First"]
   # HERE^
```

Comment: I am trying to get all music records from 2015 however the website times out when I do a broad search any idea how to go around that?

Comment: @daphweg please consider creating a new question if you have difficulties - this way at least more people can have a chance to assist you. Thank you for understanding.